# How to modify url of a state in AngularJS ui-routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am on angular 1.6. Trying to override value of a ui-router state.

Initial states as follows :

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
    abstract: true,
    parent: 'ancestor',
    url: '/parent',
    data: {
        authorities: [A,B]
    },
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/scripts/myapp/module/parent.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('child', {
    parent: 'parent',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'tabs': {
            templateUrl: 'app/scripts/myapp/module/submodule/child.html',
            controller: 'ChildController',
            controllerAs: 'childController'
        }
    }
})
.state('grandChild', {
    parent: 'child',
    url: '/{dataSource:(?:option1|option2|option3)}',
    views: {
        'body': {
            templateUrl: 'app/scripts/myapp/module/submodule/grandchild.html',
            controller: 'GrandChildController',
            controllerAs: 'grandChildController'
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        groups: ['MyService', '$transition$', function (MyService, $transition$) {
            var selectedSource = $transition$.params().dataSource ? $transition$.params().dataSource : 'option1';
            return MyService.getGroups(selectedSource);
        }]
    }
})
```

Then in one of sub-implementation I am trying to override value of url - adding **option4** for one of the state.

```
var states = $stateRegistry.deregister('grandChild');
$stateRegistry.register(states[0]);//There is one more child. For simplicity not showing here. 
states[1].url.pattern = '/{dataSource:(?:option1|option2|option3|option4)}';
$stateRegistry.register(states[1]);
```

when I do following on 'grandChild'

```
$state.go('grandChild', {dataSource: 'option4'});
```

I get error as

```
Param values not valid for state 'grandChild'. Invalid params: [ dataSource ]
```

when I  inspect $state

I see something weird.

```
$state.$current.params.datasource.type.pattern = /(?:option1|option2|option3)/
$state.$current.url.pattern = "/{dataSource:(?:option1|option2|option3|option4)}"
$state.$current.url._compiled[0] = /((?:option1|option2|option3))/
```

Comment: I might be missing something but why aren't you just declaring that option4 as a URL parameter in the state definition? [Docs here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#user-content-url-parameters)

Comment: Its sub-module inside a larger page. So cant pass that in URL. Also, code above state provider is from upstream project. So in downstream, we override as what we need. what I am guessing from above error is, original pattern is somehow compiled. But when I do url.pattern, it does not compile. Its just adding 'pattern' variable to 'url'. Question is why